# Unable to parse file when using webpack, react, react-dom

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, babeljs

I've been hammering by head with this for the last couple of hours, and I still can't solve the problem. I think I've tried almost all implementations out there, but I'm still not getting it to work.

**ERROR message**

```
ERROR in ./app/main.js
Module parse failed: /Users/DS/Code/tryouts/react-boilerplate/app/main.js Unexpected token (5:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (5:16)
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/DS/Code/tryouts/react-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:923:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/DS/Code/tryouts/react-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1490:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/Users/DS/Code/tryouts/react-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:333:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/DS/Code/tryouts/react-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:228:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/DS/Code/tryouts/react-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:207:17)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/Users/DS/Code/tryouts/react-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:154:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/DS/Code/tryouts/react-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:136:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/DS/Code/tryouts/react-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:112:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprList (/Users/DS/Code/tryouts/react-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:660:23)
    at Parser.pp.parseSubscripts (/Users/DS/Code/tryouts/react-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:252:29)
```

This is my **webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
    path = require('path');

var config = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
  entry: [
    './main.js',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /src\/.+.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        // loaders: ['babel', 'babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015'],
        loaders: ['babel', 'babel-loader']
      }
    ],
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    root: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    ],
  },
};
module.exports = config;
```

This is my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is just a simple folder structure template to use for my `React` projects.",
  "keywords": [],
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "webpack",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/dantesolis/react-boilerplate.git"
  },
  "author": "D/S",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "index.js",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/dantesolis/react-boilerplate/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/dantesolis/react-boilerplate#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "jest-cli": "^13.2.3",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "./tools/preprocessor.js",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "react"
    ],
    "testPathDirs": [
      "./src/",
      ""
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
    "react-router": "^2.6.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1"
  }
}
```

**Main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app')); <= OFFENDING LINE
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Counter from './Counter';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <div>
                <Counter />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need change `entry` from `[ 'main.js' ]` to [`'Main.js'`] because you mentioned about `Main.js` which has first letter in uppercase., also as I see from your `webpack` config, your application code are located inside `app` folder and there is no any mention about `src` folder, therefore you need change `RegExp` from `/src\/.+.js$/` to `/\.js$/`

```
 {
   test: /\.js$/,
   exclude: /node_modules/,
   loaders: ['babel', 'babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015']
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander T, the thing with `main;js` was a typo. What really solved the issue was changing the `test: /\.js$/,`. I thought that was only for the test files? Thanks once again I've been hammering my head for the last +3 hours